# How do you use AJAX to parse an XML document to see if a element exists and if it does , pass it to a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

I have been stuck on this for the past couple days. The exact question is :

"Using Ajax write an application that allows the user to enter an item name (from above XML and display a relevant message if found in the document and the information about the item quantity"

XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Recipe>
    <Name>Lime Jello Marshmellow Cottage Cheese Suprise</Name>
    <Description>My grandma's favourite (may she rest in peace).</Description>
    <Ingredients>
        <Ingredient>
            <Qty unit="box">1</Qty>
            <Item>Lime Gelatin</Item>
        </Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>
            <Qty unit="g">500</Qty>
            <Item>Multi Coloured tiny marshmallows</Item>
        </Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>
            <Qty unit="ml">500</Qty>
            <Item>Cottage Cheese</Item>
        </Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>
            <Qty unit="dash"/>
            <Item optional="1">Tabasco sauce</Item>
        </Ingredient>
    </Ingredients>
    <Instruction>
        <step>Prepare line gelatin according to package instructions</step>
    </Instruction>
</Recipe>
```

Comment: I think you can start with some xml parser like -> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

Comment: where are your attempts?

Comment: I see a task here, but no real question. In this state the "question" will most probably be closed. My advice is to add details on what you tried, code you wrote and specific problem that you encountered in the process.